# how to keep old and new deployment (Kubernetes / Openshift)

Tags: kubernetes, scripting, yaml, openshift

How to keep old and new deployment (Kubernetes / Openshift), I don't have a script to share but an example would be appreciated.

- Deployment terminates the old deployment, but in this case, I need the old and new deployments working.
- Run a job inside a POD.
- And when the job completes kill the created POD.

---

The issue with Open Shift POD.

```
 1. The current script runs and creates a single POD.
 2. As per requirement every time the script runs it should create 1 POD (which it does)
     Replica set to 1.
 3. When the script is run it creates a POD with the name ABC-1.
 4. When we run the script again it creates another POD with the name ABC-2.
 5. But when we run the script again - it terminates the old POD (ABC-1) and runs the new POD (ABC-2)
 6. what changes should be made so that,
     every time I run the script it creates a new POD but does not terminate the old PODs.
7. If I run the script 5 times - it should have all the PODs as ABC-1, ABC-2, ABC-3, ABC-4, ABC-5.
8. Replica set is 1 every time, but when we run the same script again and again it should keep the old PODs and run the new PODs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I run the script 5 times - it should have all the PODs as ABC-1, ABC-2, ABC-3, ABC-4, ABC-5.

If you want to **add** (not replace) new versions, with a different container image (and keep the old), then you have to create a new Deployment resource each time.

If you just want more replicas of the same pod, you can scale up the Deployment that you have by increasing the replica count field - but then all Pods will be identical.

Comment: Can this be incorporated (automated) in the script "that it creates a new deployment resource each time", or do we need to do it manually? An example of the same will surely help. Thanks

Comment: Everything in Kubernetes can be automated, it is designed med APIs. This can be done in many different ways, both declaratively and imperatively. An easy imperative way is `kubectl create deployment my-app --image=my-container-image` and add variables where needed. But I would recommend using it in a declarative way and add manifests to a Git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Change job name for the deployment dynamically.

The best way possible is to change the Deployment name, dynamically. In that case, it keeps all the deployments and we don't need to define kind as Job or Pod.